# Can a loop reference a list without naming it, within a global frame?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, counter, frequency

I have been tasked to group a list by frequency.  This is a very common question on SOF and so far the forum has been very educational.  However, of all the examples given, only one follows these perimeters:

- Sort the given iterable so that its elements end up in the decreasing frequency order.
- If two elements have the same frequency, they should end up in the same order as the first appearance in the iterable.

Using these two lists:

```
[4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
[17, 99, 42]
```

The following common codes given as solutions to this question have failed.

```
from collections import Counter
freq = Counter(items)

# Ex 1
# The items dont stay grouped in the final list :(

sorted(items, key = items.count, reverse=True)
sorted(items, key=lambda x: -freq[x])
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 6]


# Ex 2
# The order that the items appear in the list gets rearranged :(

sorted(sorted(items), key=freq.get, reverse=True)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 6]


# Ex 3
# With a list of integers, after the quantity gets sorted, 
# the int value gets sorted :(

sorted(items, key=lambda x: (freq[x], x), reverse=True)
[99, 42, 17]
```

I did find a solution that works great though:

```
s_list = sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True)

new_list = []
for num in s_list:
    for rep in range(freq[num]):
        new_list.append(num)
print(new_list)
```

I can't figure out how the second loop references the number of occurrences though.

I ran the process through pythontutor to visualize it and the code seems to simply know that there are four "4", two "6" and two "2" in the 'items' list.  The only solution I can think of is that python can reference a list in a global frame without it being named.  Or perhaps being able to utilize the value from the "freq" dictionary.  Is this correct?

referenced thread:
[Sort list by frequency in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815377/sort-list-by-frequency-in-python)

Comment: Try looking at the contents of freq

Comment: Suppose `freq[num]` is four. Then `for rep in range(freq[num])` will execute its body four times. If the body appends a value to a list, then the list will have four new items at the end of the loop. This all occurs without the body of the loop ever having access to an object that equals four. There's no magic here; that's just what loops do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the values of `freq` are the ones making the second loop work.

`freq` is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

In other words, `freq` is a dictionary which keys are the unique elements of `items` mapped to the amount of times they appeared in `items`.

And to illustrate your example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> items = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
>>> freq = Counter(items)
>>> freq
Counter({4: 4, 6: 2, 2: 2})
```

So when `range(freq[num])` is iterated over in your second loop, all it does is iterating over the amount of times `num` appeared in `items`.

---

**Edit 2019-02-13:** Additional information and example for Python Tutor

It looks like Python Tutor represents simple build-in types (integers, strings, ...)  as-is, and not as "objects" in their own cell.

You can see the references clearly if you use new objects instead of integer. For instance, if you were to wrap the integer such as:

```
from collections import Counter

class MyIntWrapper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

items = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
items_wrapped = [MyIntWrapper(item) for item in items]
freq = Counter(items_wrapped)

s_list = sorted(freq, key=freq.get, reverse=True)

new_list = []
for num in s_list:
    for rep in range(freq[num]):
        new_list.append(num)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!!
Why wouldn't that reference to "items" through "freq" not appear when I run the process in pythontutor?  Is it just assumed that the author(me) would know this was happening?

Comment: I edited my reply with a new example that will show the reference when run in Python Tutor. I understand it is a limitation of how to represent constant values from built-in types.