# Sort the list by its frequency in python 3 with 'key'

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

There is a question here [sort list by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815377/sort-list-by-frequency)

I don't want to bother the `collections` library. Here is my solution using 'key' in the sort

```
S = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
S.sort(reverse=True, key=S.count)
```

or

```
S.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: S.count(x))
```

But it doesn't work. Any problem with my `key` setting?
Thanks

Comment: Weird. That should (in theory) be the same as `S = sorted(S, reverse=True, key=S.count)` and that works fine...

Comment: What you are trying to do is mutating the array while iterating over it (which is what `S.count()` is implicitly doing). This is sometimes problematic. As @Nick observed, you don't have the same problem when building up a new, sorted,  array with essentially the same logic.

Comment: @JohnColeman can you explain more and summary them as `Solution`? Thanks.

Comment: @jason I don't really understand exactly what is happening here, but based on what Nick has observed, it has to be that sort of issue.

Comment: @JohnColeman that's probably it, but the return values from `count` *ought* to be the same no matter how the array has been mutated in the meantime...

Comment: @JohnColeman  Thanks for the link, I try it and something weird behavior happend in my follow-up question. Any though?

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, then please post a new question.