# How to sort dictionary values by frequency

Tags: python

Because I made my `dict` file with append list. I have the following dict file:

```
dict_1 = {'a':["1","2","d","d","d","1","2","2"], 
          'b':["1","2","e","e","5","5","5","6"]}
```

How do I sort the values by `frequency` within the `list` so I get output like:

```
dict_1 = {'a':["d","d","d","2","2","2","1","1"], 
          'b':["5","5","5","e","e","6","2","1"]}
```

The order doesn't matter for strings of the same frequency

I tried

```
result=[]
for k,v in dict_1.items():
    result.append(sorted(v, key = v.count,
                                reverse = True))
```

and got

```
[['2', 'd', 'd', 'd', '2', '2', '1', '1'],
 ['5', '5', '5', 'e', 'e', '1', '2', '6']]
```

Something is wrong with the "2" in the first list.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815377/sort-list-by-frequency)

Comment: The reason it happens is because e.g. `'2'` and `'d'` have the same number of appearances (3) within the first list, and therefore when sorting that list, there is no reason to put the individual `'2'` and `'d'` in any particular order - thus they aren't kept separate from each other. The trick to finding help with this problem is to understand that you aren't simply trying to sort, but also partition values - group like values together, sort the groups by frequency, and emit the corresponding output.

Comment: As an aside, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Evidently, the *difficulty* here is *not* "how do I apply this custom sorting to each value in a dict?", therefore you should *not include* that part of the code when asking the question. Instead, ask specifically about sorting a single list. Clearly, once you know how to do that, you can solve the entire problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `collections.Counter` with `dict` comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

cnts = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in dict_1.items()}
```

Or without `Counter`, using `list.count`:

```
cnts = {k: {i: v.count(i) for i in set(v)} for k, v in dict_1.items()}
```

Then do sort:

```
{k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: (cnts[k][x], x), reverse=True) for k, v in dict_1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['d', 'd', 'd', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1'],
 'b': ['5', '5', '5', 'e', 'e', '6', '2', '1']}
```

Note:

`key` for `sorted` returns *tuple* of `(count, itself)` so that same items remain grouped.

Comment: Thank you. I am still finding a way to do it without Counter.

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace Added an example without.

Comment: Thank you very much. This provides a different sorting perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without collections module in python.

```
dict_1 = {'a':["1","2","d","d","d","1","2","2"], 
          'b':["1","2","e","e","5","5","5","6"]}

for items in dict_1: # looping through the dictionary to get every key value pair in the dictionary

    l = dict_1.get(items) # getting the value of every key value pair in the dictionary. Here "l" is short for "list"
    print(sorted(l, key=l.count, reverse=True)) # sorting it according to frequency of the element in the list.
```

Output:

```
['2', 'd', 'd', 'd', '2', '2', '1', '1']
['5', '5', '5', 'e', 'e', '1', '2', '6']
```

You can read more about `sorted()` from [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/)

Comment: Thanks. But the output is the same as my result.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the exact code that i wrote? you are getting this result because you are appending these lists inside of another empty list

Comment: Yeah. I think I found the problem. Thank you. I did not make it explicit.

Comment: your most welcome