# Why list Sort method does not work properly?

Tags: python, list

Why doesn't it work?

```
numbers = [3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]
numbers.sort(key=lambda x: numbers.count(x))
print(numbers)
```

Why is the output still `[3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]`

sorted No such problem

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815377/sort-list-by-frequency

Comment: `list.sort` does it inplace, so you can't relate on it for sorting so `numbers = sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: numbers.count(x))` works or  copy the list  `cc = list(numbers)
    numbers.sort(key=lambda x: cc.count(x))`